# Start char counter at correct number on page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, counter

Right now my counter obviously will always begin at 350. I want it to use the correct number but I'm not sure how to call the 'left' js var in the ruby syntax.

```
<%= form_for [@status], :url => user_status_path(current_user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, id:"status_box", maxlength:350, placeholder: "Status?" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Update", id:"status_btn", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>

  <span id="counter">Characters left: 350</span>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#status_box').keyup(function () {
        var left = 350 - $(this).val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Also how can I make so when people hold down keys the counter changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to dynamically change the number of characters left in the ERB like so:

```
<span id="counter">Characters left: <%= 350 - @status.content.length %></span>
```

To get it to fire when someone his holding the key down, try binding to the `keypress` event instead of the `keyup` event.

Comment: thanks this works well. For the keypress it doesn't change the car number on holding the delete key or when pasting text. any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I'm find with the way it works with the Keyup, it just update when a key is released and that works perfectly fine. I actually think that's how the counter on this comment box works as well. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the javascript on page load so it calculates the characters left at that point:

```
  <span id="counter">Characters left: 350</span>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#status_box').keyup(function () {
        calculateCharactersLeft();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        calculateCharactersLeft();
    });
    var calculateCharactersLeft = function(){
        var left = 350 - $("#status_box").val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    }
  </script>
```

I'd personally prefer to do it this way than injecting stuff into the erb, but the choice is yours.

In fact if you pull the max length from the textarea attributes, rather than hard coding it in the JavaScript, then you only have max length value in one place, keeping your code nice and DRY.